# JSON does not post data to the requested URL

Tags: javascript, json

Trying to post some data at URL: "

```
    $(function() {
             var frm = $(document.myform);
             var data = "?lm_po_id=154668&authentication=ThisisAuth&description=ThisIsDesc";//JSON.stringify(frm.serializeArray());

//var data = JSON.stringify(frm.serializeArray()); // Also tried this

         alert(data + "I am about to POST this:\n\n" + data);
         $.postJSON = function (url, data, callback) {
                $.ajax({
                    'url': frm.attr("action"),
                    'type': 'post',
                    'processData': false,
                    'data': JSON.stringify(data),
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success: function (data) { callback(JSON.parse(data)); },
                });
            };
     });
```

This call the right function properly but when i check it in debug mode all parameters have null values, can some one help me what wrong i am doing.
Here is my HTML form

```
<form action="http://192.168.0.124:8080/Ilex-WS/service/ilexmobile/poImageUpload" name="myform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" value="158664" name="lm_po_id" /><br />
    <input type="text" value="AuthCodeMD5" name="authentication" /><br />
    <input type="text" value="584" name="imagenumber" /><br />
    <input type="text" value="ImgName.png" name="name" /><br />
    <input type="text" value="This is desc" name="description" /><br />
    <input type="file" value=""  name="uploadedimage" /><br /> 
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:document.myform.submit()"/><br />
</form>
```

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Have you done a HTTP watch to check requested URL by ajax ?

Comment: @NoobUnChained can you please explain how to check that

Comment: You mean 'data': frm.serialize() ?

Comment: @karaxuna  'data': frm.serialize()  contains values but when i check the java function it show me null

Comment: Check the requested URL by your browser developer tools to see if the parameters are passed properly. https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing your JavaScript does is alert a string.

You never bind an event handler to the form's submit method, and even if you did it wouldn't fire since you use `form.submit()` to submit the form instead of a submit button. (So this submits form encoded data instead of JSON encoded data).

You store a function in `$.postJSON`, but you never call it, and it has a local variable called `data` which would mask `var data = "?lm_po...` anyway (not that it would make sense to use that value since it is a string and you run `JSON.stringify` over `data`).

Comment: Please check that.....  var data = JSON.stringify(frm.serializeArray()); // Also tried this.... Edited the question as well

Comment: Using the return value of `serializeArray` instead of a string would make sense … but doesn't address any of the other issues with the code.

Comment: Please guide how can i call $.postJSON function on button click